# sql server with openquery using count(*) against sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-2012, openquery

I have sqlite database connected through linked server in sql server.
Following query works just fine:

```
select *
from openquery(
    eod, 
    'select id, min(dt) as mindt, max(dt) as maxdt from [tdata] group by id'
)
```

But this query returns an error:

```
select *
from openquery(
    eod,
   'select COUNT(*) as cnt from [tdata]'
)
```

Error is:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "eod" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "cnt" (compile-time ordinal 1) of object "select COUNT(*) as cnt from [tdata]" was reported to have a "DBTYPE" of 129 at compile time and 3 at run time.

What could be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The data types in the error message give clues to solve the problem. From the [Microsoft doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711251(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DBTYPE_I4 = 3, A four-byte, signed integer: LONG
DBTYPE_STR = 129, A null-terminated ANSI/DBCS character string
```

For whatever reason, at compile time the query was assumed to return a string.

Try either returning a string like it expects (conforming to a quirk is usually the fastest path to a solution):

```
select cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(20)) as cnt from [tdata]
```

or try an explicit return type, choosing a 32-bit integer in case the framework can't handle a 64-bit integer:

```
select cast(COUNT(*) as int) as cnt from [tdata]
```

---

Yet another example of Microsoft stuff "not working".

Comment: Thanks, varchar was the answer. Before posting the question I tried casting it to int. No luck. Thanks again!